# socket.io-java-client onMessage() Signature

Tags: android, json, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm using the [socket.io-java-client](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client) library to connect an Android application to a socket.io/node.js server. The GitHub page says there are two methods that can be executed when a `message` event is received:

```
public void onMessage(JSONObject json, IOAcknowledge ack)
```

and

```
public void onMessage(String data, IOAcknowledge ack)
```

How do I control which of these methods is executed? I want the first one (that takes a `JSONObject` as a parameter) to execute, but instead, the second one keeps executing.

On my server side, I switched from using `socket.emit()` to `socket.send()` in an attempt to get the first `onMessage()` to execute but this didn't work. Is there something specific I need to do on my server side to force the first `onMessage()` to run?

Here is an example of how I'm sending messages from the server:

```
socket.on('sendVerificationCode', function(data) {
    socket.send(JSON.stringify(VerifyObject.sendVerificationCode(), null, 3));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this on the server side:

```
socket.json.send({property1: 'some value', property2: 'another value'});
```

And now `onMessage()` with JSON parameter will execute.

Comment: I'm aware that I could just manually parse the object into a `JSONObject`. The intent of the question was to understand why `socket.io-java-client` was executing this method in the first place.

Comment: I think when you use socket.send(string), the second executes because you stringify the object. Otherwise if you send JSON, the first one will execute

Comment: I just did a test. When I use `JSON.stringify()` on the server side, the `onMessage(String, IOAcknowledge)` method executes on the Android device. When I don't use `JSON.stringify()` on the server side, the `on(String, IOAcknowledge, Object)` method executes on the Android device. In neither case can I get the `onMessage(JSONObject, IWAcknowledge)` to execute.

Comment: Have you tried socket.send({property1: 'value 1', property2: 'value 2'});

Comment: Yes, `onMessage(String, IOAcknowledge)` executes. I've basically tried every combination of `socket.emit('message', String)`, `socket.emit('message', Object)`, socket.send(String)` and `socket.send(Object)`. Nothing works.

Comment: I tried socket.json.send() but it still didn't work.

Comment: It is working absolutely fine on my laptop and the onMessage() with JSON argument also executed